# Sentence Classification Machine Learning API

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model, multiclass-classification

Are there any ML models or APIs that can be used to classify a sentence into one of the four types of sentences; i.e. declarative (statement), imperative (command), interrogative (question) and exclamatory (exclamation).

P.S. A web rest api would be ideal. Alternatively, if it exists, please recommend an algorithm that solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bart-large-mnli model open-sourced by facebook and is available [here](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-mnli)

Once you download all the files you can create a microservice and expose it as an API or alternatively run it in batch processing model

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. It does a pretty good job with most sentences

Comment: Also, please explore the distilled libraries of the same model. They claim to give almost same performance with double speed